# Apache Spark,NameError: name 'flatMap' is not defined

Tags: apache-spark

When I try

```
tokens = cleaned_book(flatMap(normalize_tokenize))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'flatMap' is not defined
```

where

```
cleaned_book.count()
65744
```

and

```
def normalize_tokenize(line):
...     return re.sub('\s+', ' ', line).strip().lower().split(' ')
```

On the other side

```
sc.parallelize([3,4,5]).flatMap(lambda x: range(1,x)).collect()
```

works fine from the same Pyspark shell

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Why do I have NameError?

Comment: Have you tried ```cleaned_book.flatMap(normalize_tokenize)```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is a Scala example with tokenizer that leads me to think you are looking at it wrongly.

```
def tokenize(f: RDD[String]) = {
      f.map(_.split(" "))
}

val dfsFilename = "/FileStore/tables/some.txt"
val readFileRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile(dfsFilename)
val wcounts = tokenize(spark.sparkContext.textFile(dfsFilename)).flatMap(x => x).map(word=>(word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
wcounts.collect()
```

This works fine, you need the functional . aspect, thus .flatMap and in this sequence.
The inline approach I find easier, but I note the comment also alludes to the .flatMap.